# Why statement doesn't show up when input?

Tags: c

I'm try to make a password compiler on codeblock, I need it to check if the password have an upper case and an digit in it or not but only the isupper function and strlen are working and isdigit isn't

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()//L5e$e55e
{
    int Upper= 0;
    char Lower=0;
    int digit= 0;
    int symbol=0;

    char password[8];// for the user to enter their password which is 8 character long
    printf("enter password:");
    scanf ("%s",&password);
    //this will check to see if the password is shorter than 8 character or not
        if (strlen(password)< 8) {
        printf("password have insufficient lenght !\n");
        return 1;
        }
    for (Upper= 0; Upper< 8; Upper++){

        if (isupper(password[Upper])){ // "isupper()" will return check if there an upper case character or not)
            return(1);
        }
        else if (password[Upper] == '\0');{ //this only show up if the end of the string and there isn't a upper case letter in the password
            printf("\n password should contains atleast 1 upper case character !\n");
            return (1);
        }
    }
    for (digit = 0;digit< 8; digit++){
        if (isdigit(password[digit])){ // "isdigit()" will return check if there an digit or not)
            return(1);
        }
        else if (password[digit] == '\0') { //this only show up if the end of the string and there isn't a digit in the password
            printf("\n password should contains atleast 3 digit !\n");
            return (1);
        }
    }

    printf("Password create successfully\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I input Lkjhgfds it doesn't show password should contains at least 3 digits.

Comment: `char password[8];` is **too short** for an input of 8 characters. The program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Suggestion: `char password[100]; scanf ("%99s", password);`. Which protects the buffer and allows some headroom so that it is less likely to leave any in the input buffer to mess up the next attempt. Also removed the incorrect `&`.

Comment: Any time your function `returns`, the function ends. So you'll stop as soon as you find an uppercase letter. The other checks won't be run.

Comment: @Thai Son Nguyen, Save time.  Enable all warnings.

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem

`char password[8];` is only big enough for strings up to *length* 7.  Use a wider buffer and enable all compiler warnings.

```
// char password[8];// for the user to enter their password which is 8 character long
// scanf ("%s",&password);

char password[100];
scanf ("%99s", password);
```

Answer (score 2):

In testing out your code, there was an issue right away with the character array length.  Also, with all of the "return" statements, this can make the user experience a bit frustrating as it is usually best to run through all of the tests and indicate what issue or issues exist with the password candidate entered by the user.

With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your code for your consideration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()//L5e$e55e
{
    int  Upper    = 0;
    int  Digit    = 0;
    int  Symbol   = 0;
    int  PassFail = 1;          /* Utilize this variable as a boolean value         */

    char password[100];         /* Increased as noted in the support comments       */
    printf("Enter password:");
    scanf ("%99s", password);   /* To accomodate passwords longer than 8 characters as noted in the support comments */

    // This will check to see if the password is shorter than 8 character or not
    if (strlen(password)< 8)
    {
        printf("Password has insufficient length!\n");
        PassFail = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++)
    {
        if (isupper(password[i]))  // "isupper()" will return check if there an upper case character or not
            Upper++;
    }

    if (Upper < 1)
    {
        printf("Password should contain at least one uppercase character!\n");
        PassFail = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(password[i]))  // "isdigit()" will return check if there an digit or not)
            Digit++;
    }

    if (Digit < 3)
    {
        printf("Password should contain at least 3 digits!\n");
        PassFail = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++)      /* Added a test for special characters - only a warning is potentially raised */
    {
        if ((isalpha(password[i]) == 0) && (isdigit(password[i]) == 0))
        Symbol++;
    }

    if (Symbol < 1)
        printf("Warning - no special characters were used\n");

    if (PassFail == 1)                          /* Only print that the password was successfully created if the boolean variable still is non-zero */
        printf("Password created succesfully\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the refactoring occurs throughout the code, so it was necessary to include the full program code.  Following are some of the key points.

- As noted in the good comments, the original size of the password character array was too small to contain eight characters as there needs to be accommodation for the terminating character '\0', so at the very least, the size of this character array would need to be increased to "9".
- Using the suggestion within the good comments, the character array size was increased to "100" to offer up larger password candidates.
- An additional "pass/fail" variable was added to act as a Boolean value for testing, such that if any test fails, this value can be set to a value of "0" mimicking a False situation.
- After each test "for" loop, a check of the required or desired condition is made and if the mandatory condition is not met, the Boolean variable is set to "0", and subsequent tests can still be carried out.
- There is a counter for symbolic characters defined, but there was no test for symbolic characters, so a simple test was added for that, which potentially would result in a warning if no special characters are used in the password.
- Once all of the tests have been processed, the declaration of a successful password is only made if none of the tests set the "PassFail" variable to "0".

Performing various test scenarios, following was some sample terminal output, including testing your example.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ValidatePassword/bin/Release$ ./ValidatePassword 
Enter password:Short
Password has insufficient length!
Password should contain at least 3 digits!
Warning - no special characters were used
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ValidatePassword/bin/Release$ ./ValidatePassword 
Enter password:uuuuuuuuuuu
Password should contain at least one uppercase character!
Password should contain at least 3 digits!
Warning - no special characters were used
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ValidatePassword/bin/Release$ ./ValidatePassword 
Enter password:Cd847$iou
Password created succesfully
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/ValidatePassword/bin/Release$ ./ValidatePassword 
Enter password:L5e$e55e
Password created succesfully
```

The take-away here is be cognizant of the necessary size requirements of character arrays along with the design of the user experience.  And it would probably be helpful to delve into some C programming tutorials to get a better understanding of loops, arrays, and so forth.

Comment: 'A' for effort, and code isn't bad, but you should point out you can avoid multiple iterations over the same input by including all checks during a single iteration of the input.

Comment: Very true.  Always room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments and other answers, the buffer used is too small to store the minimum 8 characters of a candidate password as a NUL terminated C string. `scanf()` hasn't restricted the number of characters the user can type (buffer overrun possible), nor is its return code verified. The incorrect use of `return` and use of the character counters as loop variables demonstrates a lack of understanding of the problem.

Here's a version that's been extended to perform more tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void ) {
    int fail = 1; // pessimism

do {
    char pwrd[100], *cp = pwrd; // be generous

    printf( "Enter candidate password: " );
    fgets( pwrd, sizeof pwrd, stdin ); // prevent buffer overrun
    strtok( pwrd, "\r\n" ); // trim CR LF

    if( strlen( pwrd ) > 16 ) { puts( "Too long" ); continue; }

    fail = 0; // optimism
    int hasUpper = 0, hasLower = 0, hasDigit = 0, hasSymbl = 0, hasCntrl = 0; // counters
    unsigned char uch; // <ctype.h> functions want "unsigned chars"
    while( (uch = (unsigned char)*cp++) != 0 ) {
        // perform various tests
        hasUpper += isupper( uch );
        hasLower += islower( uch );
        hasDigit += isdigit( uch );
        hasSymbl += !isalpha( uch ) && !isdigit( uch ) && !isspace( uch );
        hasCntrl += iscntrl( uch ) || uch == ' ';
    }
    char *fmt = "Fail #%d - Must contain %s\n"; // consistent report string
    if( cp-pwrd <= 8 ) printf( fmt, ++fail, "8+ characters" );
    if( !hasUpper    ) printf( fmt, ++fail, "1+ uppercase" );
    if( !hasLower    ) printf( fmt, ++fail, "1+ lowercase" );
    if(  hasDigit <3 ) printf( fmt, ++fail, "3+ digits" );
    if( !hasSymbl    ) printf( fmt, ++fail, "1+ non-alpha/non-digit" );
    if(  hasCntrl    ) printf( fmt, ++fail, "no spaces and no control codes" );

    printf( "Password '%s' %s\n\n", pwrd, fail ? "invalid" : "checks out" ); // final judgement
} while( fail ); // retry until succeed (or program halted)

    return !fail; // return code is useful to calling script
}
```

Use:

```
Enter candidate password: passwrd
Fail #1 - Must contain 8+ characters
Fail #2 - Must contain 1+ uppercase
Fail #3 - Must contain 3+ digits
Fail #4 - Must contain 1+ non-alpha/non-digit
Password 'passwrd' invalid

Enter candidate password: pass wrd
Fail #1 - Must contain 1+ uppercase
Fail #2 - Must contain 3+ digits
Fail #3 - Must contain 1+ non-alpha/non-digit
Fail #4 - Must contain no spaces and no control codes
Password 'pass wrd' invalid

Enter candidate password: PASSWORD
Fail #1 - Must contain 1+ lowercase
Fail #2 - Must contain 3+ digits
Fail #3 - Must contain 1+ non-alpha/non-digit
Password 'PASSWORD' invalid

Enter candidate password: P455word
Fail #1 - Must contain 1+ non-alpha/non-digit
Password 'P455word' invalid

Enter candidate password: P455w@rd
Password 'P455w@rd' checks out
```

Hoping this has been useful and, perhaps, educational.

Aside: requiring 3 digits, instead of 1, promotes a weaker password. Those 3 characters can vary by 10^3 (1000) cases. Instead, a minimum of 1 digit would mean the other two could be, for instance, other alphabetic characters. The combination for those 3 alone would then be 10 * 52 * 52 (27040). Requiring 1 digit may be fine. Requiring 3, when most people will only use 8 character passwords, defeats the purpose somewhat.

Comment: I like it, but since my eyes are getting old, I vote for another space between `... <=8)printf ...` and each of the blocks below to keep it tidy `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Noted and altered! Sometimes the "layout" is as critical (if not **more**) to the _seeing_ what the code is doing (or supposed to do.) Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: I saw what you were doing and liked the single-line layout of the conditional expressions -- that did make the tests clear `:p`